# Keeping out VBE Editor Window Flicker

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

There have been posts about this, but it seems I'm doing something wrong, as the window is still flickering. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
Private Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndLock As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal ClassName As String, ByVal WindowName As String) As Long
170   oExcel.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
180   VBEHwnd = FindWindow("wndclass_desked_gsk", oExcel.VBE.MainWindow.Caption)
190   If VBEHwnd Then LockWindowUpdate VBEHwnd
200   With MB.VBProject.VBComponents(MB.Worksheets(sht.Name).CodeName).CodeModule
210       .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc("Click", printbut.Name) + 1, String:=vbCrLf & "Call Sheet4.printbutton"
220   End With
230   oExcel.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
240   LockWindowUpdate 0&
```

What am I doing wrong? (The code is based on CPearson's code).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check if `VBEHwnd` actually returns something. Change the line `If VBEHwnd Then LockWindowUpdate VBEHwnd` to `If VBEHwnd Then LockWindowUpdate VBEHwnd Else MsgBox "Window not found"` What happens?

Comment: I had run it in debug mode, and it did return True and processes the line 'LockWindowUpdate VBEHwnd', but it flickered nonetheless.

Comment: `VBEHwnd` will never return `True` or `False` If a window is found, then it should return a number. However if you didn't see a message box using the code above then it means the window was found. Will look at your code again when I am back. I am out at the moment....

Comment: What I meant is that the IF didn't return False, it returned a number. Perhaps I should mention that this is a VB6 program automating Excel.

Comment: Siddharth, did you get a chance to test the code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried everything and couldn't get it to work. So another option (not preferable) that I ended up using is:

```
170   oExcel.VBE.mainwindow.Visible = False
180   curPos = oExcel.VBE.mainwindow.Left
190   oExcel.VBE.mainwindow.Left = 10000
200   With MB.VBProject.VBComponents(MB.Worksheets(sht.Name).CodeName).CodeModule
210       .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc("Click", printbut.Name) + 1, String:=vbCrLf & "Call Sheet4.printbutton"
220   End With
230   oExcel.VBE.mainwindow.Visible = False
240   oExcel.VBE.mainwindow.Left = curPos
```